# WvDial serial communication not working with uart /dev/ttySAC4, but works with `screen`

Tags: modem, ppp, wvdial, uart

I have embedded system based on Samsung Artik 710 board connected to Fibocom G510 cellular modem module via UART (two lines - RX and TX).

When I try to communicate with modem using `screen` - modem responds to AT commands and looks like it's working:

```
$ screen /dev/ttySAC4
```

.

```
AT
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"ip","playmetric"
OK
ATDT*99***1#
CONNECT
}&} } } } }#}$ďż˝#}%}&ďż˝}"Ú}'}"}(}"ďż˝ďż˝

(...)
```

When I try with `wvdial` - looks like there is no serial communication at all.

```
[root@artik ~]# wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot set information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: AT
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: AT
--> Modem not responding.
[root@artik ~]#
```

My `/etc/wvdial.conf`

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttySAC4
# Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0 # Tested  Raspberry Pi with /dev/ttyUSB0 modem
Init1 = AT
Init2 = AT
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"ip","playmetric"
Username=" "
Password = " "
Phone = "*99***1#"
Dial Command = ATDT
Stupid Mode = yes
Dial Attempts = 0
Auto DNS = off
```

My system:

> Linux artik 4.4.113 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 30 15:29:10 EDT 2018
>   aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

strace

```
[root@artik ~]# strace wvdial
execve("/usr/bin/wvdial", ["wvdial"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x133c1000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34896, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 34896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7192000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libwvstreams.so.4.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0000\377\3\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=847104, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7191000
mmap(NULL, 912256, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7092000
mprotect(0x7fa7158000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa7168000, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc6000) = 0x7fa7168000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libwvutils.so.4.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0 \337\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=159312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1278296, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6f59000
mprotect(0x7fa6f7e000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6f8e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fa6f8e000
mmap(0x7fa6f90000, 1053016, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6f90000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libwvbase.so.4.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0P\331\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=547856, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 573648, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6ecc000
mmap(0x7fa6f4c000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x80000) = 0x7fa6f4c000
mmap(0x7fa6f52000, 24784, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6f52000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libuniconf.so.4.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0@\v\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=376736, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7190000
mmap(NULL, 441456, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6e60000
mprotect(0x7fa6eb8000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6ec8000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x58000) = 0x7fa6ec8000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\340\246\10\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1554312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1630888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6cd1000
mprotect(0x7fa6e41000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6e50000, 49152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16f000) = 0x7fa6e50000
mmap(0x7fa6e5c000, 12968, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6e5c000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\350\371\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1265992, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1335960, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6b8a000
mprotect(0x7fa6cb8000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6cc7000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12d000) = 0x7fa6cc7000
mmap(0x7fa6ccd000, 12952, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6ccd000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0 \36\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa718f000
mmap(NULL, 155912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6b63000
mprotect(0x7fa6b79000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6b88000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7fa6b88000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\20`\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=366504, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 430208, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6af9000
mprotect(0x7fa6b48000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6b58000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4f000) = 0x7fa6b58000
mmap(0x7fa6b62000, 128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b62000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\200\34\6\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1639112, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1717680, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6955000
mprotect(0x7fa6ac1000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6ad1000, 147456, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16c000) = 0x7fa6ad1000
mmap(0x7fa6af5000, 13744, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6af5000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\260(\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=70664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa718e000
mmap(NULL, 134896, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6934000
mprotect(0x7fa6945000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6954000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x7fa6954000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\360\v\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30896, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 283048, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa68ee000
mprotect(0x7fa68f5000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6904000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fa6904000
mmap(0x7fa6906000, 184744, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6906000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\340$\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51656, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 115168, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa68d1000
mprotect(0x7fa68dd000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa68ec000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xb000) = 0x7fa68ec000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa718d000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\300R\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=643136, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 705144, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6824000
mprotect(0x7fa68c0000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa68cf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9b000) = 0x7fa68cf000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\320\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 73960, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6811000
mprotect(0x7fa6813000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6822000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fa6822000
close(3)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\20+\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=108944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6810000
mmap(NULL, 213544, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa67db000
mprotect(0x7fa67f5000, 61440, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa6804000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7fa6804000
mmap(0x7fa6806000, 37416, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6806000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa67da000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa67d9000
mprotect(0x7fa6cc7000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6804000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6822000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa68cf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa68ec000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6904000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6ad1000, 102400, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b58000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b88000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa67d8000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa67d7000
mprotect(0x7fa6e50000, 40960, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6f4c000, 20480, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6f8e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa7168000, 28672, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6ec8000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x427000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fa719d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fa7192000, 34896)             = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[ILL TRAP BUS FPE SEGV RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {0x7fa69ba7d8, ~[ILL TRAP BUS FPE SEGV RTMIN RT_1], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, ~[ILL TRAP BUS FPE KILL SEGV STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
--- SIGILL {si_signo=SIGILL, si_code=ILL_ILLOPC, si_addr=0x7fa69ba828} ---
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[ILL TRAP BUS FPE KILL SEGV STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x133c1000
brk(0x133f3000)                         = 0x133f3000
gettimeofday({1535476076, 539718}, NULL) = 0
dup(2)                                  = 3
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x4061a4, [TERM], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x4061a4, [INT], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x4061a4, [HUP], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/wvdial.conf", F_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/wvdial.conf", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=288, ...}) = 0
gettimeofday({1535476076, 542825}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], NULL, NULL)    = 1 (in [4])
gettimeofday({1535476076, 543205}, NULL) = 0
read(4, "[Dialer Defaults]\nModem = /dev/t"..., 1024) = 288
gettimeofday({1535476076, 544035}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], NULL, NULL)    = 1 (in [4])
gettimeofday({1535476076, 544388}, NULL) = 0
read(4, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/root/.wvdialrc", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
gettimeofday({1535476076, 546258}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "--> ", 4--> )                     = 4
write(3, "WvDial: Internet dialer version "..., 36WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61) = 36
write(3, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lock/LCK..ttySAC4", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NONBLOCK, 0644) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getpid()                                = 11826
write(4, "     11826\n", 11)            = 11
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttySAC4", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
gettimeofday({1535476076, 551931}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {0, 0}, NULL)  = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476076, 552290}, NULL) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCGSERIAL, 0x7feba09818)     = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCSSERIAL)                   = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
gettimeofday({1535476076, 552782}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "--> ", 4--> )                     = 4
write(3, "Cannot set information for seria"..., 39Cannot set information for serial port.) = 39
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
write(4, "\r", 1)                       = 1
nanosleep({0, 10000000}, NULL)          = 0
write(4, "\r", 1)                       = 1
nanosleep({0, 10000000}, NULL)          = 0
write(4, "\r", 1)                       = 1
nanosleep({0, 10000000}, NULL)          = 0
write(4, "\r", 1)                       = 1
nanosleep({0, 10000000}, NULL)          = 0
write(4, "\r", 1)                       = 1
nanosleep({0, 10000000}, NULL)          = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 500000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
nanosleep({0, 10000000}, NULL)          = 0
gettimeofday({1535476077, 130465}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {0, 0}, NULL)  = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476077, 131134}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1535476077, 131458}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(3, "--> ", 4--> )                     = 4
write(3, "Initializing modem.", 19Initializing modem.)     = 19
write(3, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(4, "\r\r\r\r\r", 5)               = 5
gettimeofday({1535476077, 133553}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {0, 100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476077, 234525}, NULL) = 0
write(4, "AT\r", 3)                     = 3
gettimeofday({1535476077, 235221}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "--> ", 4--> )                     = 4
write(3, "Sending: AT", 11Sending: AT)             = 11
write(3, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
gettimeofday({1535476077, 236560}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {5, 0}, NULL)  = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476082, 238733}, NULL) = 0
write(4, "ATQ0\r", 5)                   = 5
gettimeofday({1535476082, 239425}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "--> ", 4--> )                     = 4
write(3, "Sending: ATQ0", 13Sending: ATQ0)           = 13
write(3, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
gettimeofday({1535476082, 240807}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {0, 500000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476082, 742708}, NULL) = 0
write(4, "AT\r", 3)                     = 3
gettimeofday({1535476082, 743404}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "--> ", 4--> )                     = 4
write(3, "Re-Sending: AT", 14Re-Sending: AT)          = 14
write(3, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
gettimeofday({1535476082, 744745}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {5, 0}, NULL)  = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476087, 746926}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1535476087, 747288}, NULL) = 0
write(3, "--> ", 4--> )                     = 4
write(3, "Modem not responding.", 21Modem not responding.)   = 21
write(3, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
gettimeofday({1535476087, 748780}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {0, 0}, NULL)  = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476087, 749438}, NULL) = 0
write(4, "\r", 1)                       = 1
gettimeofday({1535476087, 750058}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [], [4], [], {0, 200000000}, NULL) = 1 (out [4], left {0, 199983349})
gettimeofday({1535476087, 750851}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1535476087, 751147}, NULL) = 0
pselect6(5, [4], [], [], {0, 0}, NULL)  = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({1535476087, 751792}, NULL) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
write(4, "+++", 3)                      = 3
nanosleep({1, 500000000}, NULL)         = 0
write(4, "ATH\r", 4)                    = 4
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
nanosleep({0, 100000000}, NULL)         = 0
ioctl(4, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CAR|TIOCM_DSR]) = 0
ioctl(4, TCFLSH, TCIOFLUSH)             = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCGETS, {B57600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, TCFLSH, TCIOFLUSH)             = 0
close(4)                                = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lock/LCK..ttySAC4", 0) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Run `strace wvdial` and verify it's really trying to open `/dev/ttySAC4`. Also "cannot set information for serial port" looks suspicious, strace may show what happens.

Comment: @dirkt strace result added

Comment: You can see that the TIOCGSERIAL ioctl fails, unfortunately it doesn't show what parameters it wants to set. It's possible that the failed call puts the modem into a non-responsive state. Among other things, TIOCGSERIAL sets the baud rate, so try to add some `Baud = ...` values to the `wvdial.conf`, and see if you can make the error go away.

Comment: I tried also with baud config line. I configured this connection without WvDial (ppp and chat script) and it works. Maybe WvDial is bugged or doesn't work without flow control?

Comment: No idea, but the theory is still that `wvdial` is trying to set something which would normally work, but in this case puts the device in a "ignore everything" state. Next step would be to look at the `wvdial` source code, see what it is trying to set, prevent it from setting that and see if that makes the error go away. Looking at what `stty` has to say before and after `wvdial` runs may also give a hint.